# intersection of sets corresponding to free ultrafiler

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory, c-star-algebras, filters

If $\omega \in \beta \Bbb N\setminus \Bbb N$,we define $S_{\omega}=\{(x_n) \in \prod M_n(\Bbb C):lim_{n \to \omega}tr_n(x_n)=0\}$

Is the intersection $\cap_{\omega \in \beta \Bbb N \setminus \Bbb N}S_{\omega}$ empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $x=(x_n)$ where $x_n=\tfrac1n\,I_n$. Then $\operatorname{tr}_n(x_n)=\tfrac1n\to0$, so $x\in S_\omega$ for all $\omega$.

Comment: An ultrafilter over $\mathbb N$ always contains $\mathbb N$. Not sure how it relates to the question, though.

Comment: My thought was wrong:I mistook the intersections of $S_{\omega}$ as empty set.What is the intersetions of $S_{\omega}$?Is it the $S_{\mathcal{F}}$,where $\mathcal{F}$ is the cofinite ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$?